# Confused on VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL with VkSemaphore

Tags: synchronization, semaphore, vulkan

I'm reading [Vulkan Tutorial "Rendering and Presentation" chapter](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Drawing/Rendering_and_presentation), the "Subpass dependencies" section confused me a lot.

It says: VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL is reference to the commands outside the render pass, but, the problem is, there is no commands outside the render pass in that Hello-Triangle example, and I didn't see spec or somewhere says it will automatically create a command block by semaphore, I'm confused now, what does the `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` mean if there is no command before render pass?

Answer (score 2):

`VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` references commands recorded\submitted before `vkCmdBeginRenderPass` or after `vkCmdEndRenderpass`.

---

In a case of a 101 example, the adjacent use is just swapchain, which requires an semaphore on acquire and semaphore on present. There is actually concrete note about this use case in the specification, at the end of [7.4.2. Semaphore Waiting](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-semaphores-waiting).

Now, semaphore signal (before you present) already covers all previous memory access on the device, so you are all set without any further synchronization. But for educational purposes and code readability, it cannot hurt to add that dependency explicitly anyway:

```
VkSubpassDependency presentDependency{
    0, // srcSubpass
    VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL, // dstSubpass
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT, // srcStageMask
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT, // dstStageMask
    VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT, // srcAccessMask
    0, // dstAccessMask
    0, // dependencyFlags
};
```

Note `dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT`, which practically means "synchronize with nothing". The `srcStageMask` covers your store op, but it would have been covered implicitly even if you do not list any Dependency.

Now the semaphore wait (for your swapchain image acquire semaphore) is sneaky. There's a sneaky `vkQueueSubmit` parameter, the `pWaitDstStageMask`. That parameter says the semaphore will not be waited sooner than the pipeline stage in `pWaitDstStageMask`. So you must actually put a dependency there that pushes the layout transition from your render pass after the semaphore wait:

```
pWaitDstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;

VkSubpassDependency acquireDependency{
    VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL, // srcSubpass
    0, // dstSubpass
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT, // srcStageMask
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT, // dstStageMask
    0, // srcAccessMask
    VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT, // dstAccessMask
    VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT, // dependencyFlags
};
```

Note that `pWaitDstStageMask = srcStageMask`, so an [execution dependency chain](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-dependencies) is formed with the semaphore wait. This dependency also forces the layout transition away from `initialLayout` to happen inbetween the semaphore wait and the renderpass load op.

Refer to [this diagram](https://github.com/krOoze/Hello_Triangle/blob/master/doc/Schema.pdf) about the synchronization, and what and why it is needed:

[image]

---

For a more complex app it actually gets simpler. Refer to [official synch. examples](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/wiki/Synchronization-Examples). You simply add a dependency there that is appropriate for the previous\next usage of the image.

E.g. if you perform compute (`vkCmdDispatch`) after the render pass, then you simply add a `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` dependency with `dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT`.

Comment: but what does `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` refer to? there is no command recorded/submitted before the `vkCmdBeginRenderPass`.

Comment: @AlanJian: It refers to everything submitted to that queue (or otherwise in the dependency chain) before the render pass begin command gets executed in the queue. If beginning a render pass is literally the first command in the first command buffer in the first submit operation to this queue you ever do, then the source scope is empty.

Comment: @NicolBolas So it's not technically means "semaphore signaled"? it is just "last drawcall writing completed", the "semaphore signaled" should be `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT` completed this frame

Comment: @AlanJian In this case `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL + VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT` it refers to your semaphore wait, which happens no later than `pWaitDstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`. It is sorta special case. Two synch primitives, if the stage parameters overlap, form a so called [execution dependency chain](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-dependencies).

Comment: @AlanJian I have trouble understanding your second comment.

Comment: @krOoze isn't `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` refer to commands submitted last frame(if there is a "last frame" exist)?
So `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL + VK_PIPELINE_SAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT` means: commands submitted last frame completed the color attachment out stage?
which is not technically means the semaphore is signaled.

Comment: @AlanJian: As stated in my answer, "external" in the source of a subpass dependency means "everything before the render pass was executed". And "everything" means *everything*. Not just "last frame", but everything up to the point where the queue encounters `vkCmdBeginRenderPass`.

Comment: The problem here is, layout transition must happen after semaphore signaled, but it doesn't. also, the semaphore will reset to unsignaled every frame, so commands sent before to queue don't help a lot, there must be some commands submit after semaphore reset, which means it is waiting the semaphore signaled(again). but, there is only commands in the current renderpass is sent after semaphore reset, so, I can't understand why commands sent before indicates the semaphore is siganled(again)?

Comment: It seems related to "Semaphore wait operation", but I'm not sure, cuz I can't find enough article says what does semaphore wait operations do clearly.

Answer (score 1):

The source operation defines the source command scope for the dependency, the set of commands that will have a "happens before" relationship to the commands in the destination scope.

Scopes are usually queue-wide (technically, they also include things in the intra-queue dependency chain based on semaphores and the like, but nevermind that now). So when a source scope talks about all of the commands before some point, that means *all commands* that the queue executed before that point in sequence of commands.

External as the source "subpass" in a subpass dependency means everything before the render pass. That's *everything* before the render pass. Every command processed by that queue up until the moment it processes the `vkCmdBeginRenderPass` command.

If the very first command processed by a queue happens to be a begin render pass command, then the external source scope is an empty set. But there's nothing wrong with that; the synchronization is essentially a no-op. So everything proceeds as normal.